# What was Suzie implying on the witness stand?

Tags: dialogue, wild-things

> **Suzie**: Kelly's pissed at Lombardo too. She's in love with him, I mean, he's been her whole fantasy since her old man died...

When Suzie said this, was she suggesting that Kelly had incestuous fantasies about her father when he was alive?

Answer (score 2):

No. At least, not necessarily (and not obviously).

Suzie just means that one of the ways in which Kelly dealt or seemed to deal with the death of her father, was to concentrate more on (her love for) Sam Lombardo.

There might be some [Freudian theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus_complex) behind this (Sam repeatedly calls Kelly a "*good girl*", and there's a lot more patronizing going on (although that could just be 'the times')).

> Remember as well that this monologue was made up to suit the goals of the protagonists, so it had to make a clear impact on the judge and jury. But, as the film centres on two teenage girls and two older men who all have more or less intimate relationships, this could also have been a quip, a jest, or a tongue-in-cheek remark improvised by Suzie, maybe even to try to provoke Kelly.